# Is a subset contained in a union of its superset?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

For context, I'm taking an introductory real analysis course, and our current topic is intervals. One of the questions requires to prove that, for every $x, y$ in some real interval $I$, with $x<y$, the interval $[x,y]$ is also contained in $I$.

I'm taking a shortcut by proving it's a subset of an open interval $I = (a,b)$, then **arguing that $[x,y] \subset (I \cup G)$, for some arbitrary set $G \subset \mathbb R$**. From there, changing $G$ should span all the cases I'm looking for.

My question: **is the provided argument sufficient?** Is it a non-trivial fact in set theory? Or am I wrongly using my thesis to prove the hypothesis? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a shortcut, since the proof for the claim is pretty straightforward. Besides, at best $[x,y] \subseteq I \cup G$ only lets you claim the elements of $[x,y]$ are in one or the other. I suppose if you can prove it for all $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, somehow, then the case $G = \varnothing$ gets you the end result. But it seems roundabout at best and far from the intention of the exercise.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thank you for the comment! My goal with this is to prove that $[x,y]$ is further contained in $I = (a,b)$ but closed on one side, closed on both sides, and in $(a, +\infty)$ or $(-\infty, b)$. In my opinion, it would be less efficient to repeat the proof six times...

Comment: My argument would just be to note that

$$[x,y] = \{ z \mid z = (1-t)x + yt \text{ for some } t \in [0,1] \}$$

With this definition of an interval, one need only restrict $t$ a bit to show that an interval contains subintervals.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer This is a very unique way of defining this interval! I will consider it and try again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question in your title, and I hope that it gives you some insight. Yes, a subset is contained in any union of its superset with a different set.

I would say this is a trivial set theoretic fact, however if you don't trust a statement it is always worth going about a proof for it because maths is all about proving to ourselves that we're right. Here's a proof for it:

Lets take $A \subset B$ but $A \not \subset B \cup C$ for some set $C$. This implies there exists $a \in A$ such that $a \in B$ (by the first fact) but $a \not \in B \cup C$. This is a very clear contradiction.

I question you saying you're going to "prove it's a subset of the open interval $I = (a,b)$." Surely doing that is what you're trying to do? You can then just union on the end points to get the half open and closed intervals.

Comment: Thank you, this was absolutely what I was going for. I didn't make it clear, now that I notice, that this far I have already proven that $[x,y]$ is a subset of $I$, thus a subset of $I \cup G$. The gimmick was defining $G$ as one of the endpoints, both, or another interval that extends one side to infinity, to not repeat the proof many times. But now I'm sure there's room to do so!

Comment: @dayhhhdreaming Absolutely brilliant. I mean what I said when I said that its always a good idea to question statements and see if you can prove them, even if someone else has said that they're trivial.